# Make meta query treat meta_value as 1 or 0

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

My products have no in-stock status, just a quantity in stock. Is there any way to make meta query to treat its value as 0 or 1? Like, first the values that are not 0, then that are 0.

My query as it is right now:

```
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
   'quantity_total' => array(
            'key'     => 'total_quantity',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
   ),
   'price_lowest_first' => array(
            'key'     => 'main_price',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    )
),
'orderby' => array(
   'quantity_total' => 'DESC',
   'price_lowest_first' => 'ASC'
)
```

**EDIT:**

For now, I ended up using an 'in-stock' flag, and here's my code:

```
//sort by total quantity
if($sort !== '4'){      
    $args['meta_query']['in_stock'] = array(
            'key' => '1C_in_stock',
           'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    );
    $args['orderby']  = array( 
        'in_stock' => 'DESC'
    );
}

//apply sort preferences to arguments
switch($sort){
    #by stock status
    case '1':
        // '1' is default, do not want to move it to the default clause yet.
        break;

   #sort by price: lower first
    case '2':
        $args['meta_query']['price_lowest_first'] = array(
                'key' => '1C_price'
               'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );  
        $args['orderby']['price_lowest_first']  = 'ASC';
        break;

    #sort by price:higher first
    case '3':
        $args['meta_query']['price_highest_first'] = array(
            'key' => '1C_price',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        );
        $args['orderby']['price_highest_first']  = 'DESC';
        break;

    #sort randomly
    case '4':
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        break;
}
```

But is there a query to order items by non-zero and zero quantity? And then, order each group by price.

Comment: You're using `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` in your meta query clauses, so the meta value is already being treated as a number, but you would want to use the `DECIMAL` type for the price meta. Or am I not understanding what you mean? And what problem you're having with your (meta) query? Are the posts not getting sorted properly? If so, can you post sample data and the outcome you're currently getting and the one you're hoping to get?

Comment: Hey Sally! Thank you for stopping by! My posts get ordered properly, but that's not what I want )) . What I want is the system to treat product quantity like it's either 0 or 1. That is, I want the products with any quantitiy to be shown first, ordered by price (regardless of actual quantity), and then, the ones with the quantity of 0, ordered by price again. I could not figure it out and ended up writing an 'in-stock' flag into my database. I wonder if it's possible at all, like divide into 2 groups by non-zero-quantity and then order each of them by price, without the flag.

Comment: I've added my solution to the question, alhough it doesn't really answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If I understand it correctly..*

What you're looking for can be achieved using the `CASE` statement in MySQL, where you would use the following in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
# group the quantity meta into two groups
CASE
    # group one - all quantities that are 1 or more; we flag them as "1"
    WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 > 0 THEN 1

    # group two - all quantities that are 0 or less; we flag them as "2"
    WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 <= 0 THEN 2
END ASC
```

Where `wp_postmeta.meta_value` is the value of the `total_quantity` meta which is the first one in your meta query, and the `+0` means we're casting the meta value as a number.

And to add that `CASE` statement to the `ORDER BY` clause, you can use the [`posts_orderby` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/). Here's an example using closure with a private variable:

```php
// *Private variable used with the closure below.
$_do_filter = true;

add_filter( 'posts_orderby',
    function ( $orderby ) use ( &$_do_filter ) {
        if ( $_do_filter ) {
            $orderby = "CASE\n" .
                "  WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 > 0 THEN 1\n" .
                "  WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 <= 0 THEN 2\n" .
            "END ASC, $orderby";
        }

        return $orderby;
    }
);

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'          => 'AND',
        'quantity_total'    => array(
            'key'     => 'total_quantity',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'price_lowest_first' => array(
            'key'     => 'main_price',
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL(5, 2)',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'    => array(
        // we already have the CASE statement, so this is no longer needed
//      'quantity_total'     => 'DESC',
        'price_lowest_first' => 'ASC',
    ),
    // ... your other args.
) );

// Disable the filter.
$_do_filter = false;

// Then run your loop here..
// while ( $query->have_posts() ) ...
```

And note that for the `main_price` meta, I set the `type` to `DECIMAL(5, 2)` so that the prices would be sorted by taking into account the decimal.

Comment: Sally, I suspect you got your staff on Roke Island, because this seems to be a deeper level of WordPress magic. ) Bravo )

Comment: Glad it helped. :) But actually, in the closure, you should do `global $wpdb;` and then use `{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value` instead of hard-coding `wp_postmeta.meta_value` ... sorry about that 

Comment: Hey, Sally, by the way, which one do you think is more efficient, `add_filter( 'posts_orderby')` or an `'in_stock'` meta for a product? A simple 'is in stock' flag is -kind of- simpler, because there are no `CASE` statement involved, and such flag is easy to set on product import, but again, additional meta will be fetched from DB by get_post_meta countless times everywhere, like on product category pages. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry if this disappointed you, but I don't know the answer to your question on the `CAST` vs the extra 'is in stock' flag/meta. However, since you have access to the data, then you could run your own tests and compare the results between using the `CAST` statement and the 'is in stock' flag?

Comment: And actually, now that you asked, I think a much better option (than using the 'is in stock' meta) is use a custom taxonomy (e.g. `stock_status`) and create the terms `1` (or `In Stock`) and `0` (or `Not In Stock`), then assign your products to the `1` or `0` term. You would still need the `CAST` (or custom SQL in the `ORDER BY` clause) when sorting the posts (i.e. if you want them grouped like your originally asked), but terms are [indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) (and meta values are not), so filtering/searching by the terms is much faster than by the meta

Comment: Sally, this makes a lot of sence! Thank you. Also, such meta would add as many unindexed meta values as there are products, which isn't good either. Well, now I think I should redesign some processes on my site )